# Datatable send current page number

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable

I've been try to send current page number to server by overwrite a variable called **pgno**

here is my code :

```
function fill_datatable(status='',pgno='') 
{
    var pgno = 0;
    table = $('.tb_scoin_available').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ordering"  : false,
        "infoCallback": function( settings, start, end, max, total, pre ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var pageInfo = api.page.info();
            pgno = pageInfo.page+1;
            return pgno;
        },
        "ajax":{
            "url": base_url+'/adminPath/management_scoin/ajaxGetScoinAvailable',
            "type": "POST",
            "data":{ _token: csrf_token, status : status,pgno : pgno}
        },
        "columnDefs": [ { orderable: false} ],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "no" },
            { "data": "created_at" },
            { "data": "serial_scoin" },
            { "data": "unit_scoin" },
            { "data": "unit_scoin_desc" },
            { "data": "unit_scoin_sc" },
            { "data": "unit_scoin_idr" },
        ],

    }); 
}
```

when I try to alert on infoCallback :
`alert(pgno)` the variable already overwrited, but when I try to dump the request on backend the **pgno** POST give me null result like this :

[image: screenshot]

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the table page with the page() function, no need for the whole "page.info". It's better explained in Datatable's API: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()

The method you're trying to access is only to get the information, not to set it. That is probably why it isn't working. Check their docs for better understanding of their API: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()

EDIT:

You can get the current page through a simple calculation. Since you're using serverSide processing, you already have **start** and **length**. You just need to do start/length + 1 and you will get the current page number.

Comment: here I am confused how to passing the page to backend,with the trigger when user click the page number ?

Comment: You already have the data you need ;) 
Datatables provide you with both: start and length. With those, you can calculate the current page doing this: data.start / data.length + 1

Comment: ooh , so i can get current page on backend by this formula ? data.start / data.length + 1

Comment: Exactly, my man. I added that to my answer so it helps others :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

```
$('#grid-pages').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/ld+json"
        },
        infoCallback: function (settings, start, end, max, total, pre) {
            settings.api = this.api();
        },
        ajax: {
            url: '/api/pages',
            pages: 5, // number of pages to cache
            data: function(data, settings) {
                return {
                    page: settings.api === undefined ? 1 : settings.api.page.info().page + 1
                }
            }
        },
    });
```